# IIS Failed Request Tracing not working

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have setup Failed Requests Tracing on IIS 8 but it is not logging errors as expected; there is an ASP Classic page that generates "500 Internal Server Error" but the FailedReqLogFiles folder is empty. Here is my setup:

- Failed Requests Tracing Module is installed
- In order to trace error #500 generated by ASP Classic pages I have setup these rules:

```xml
<traceFailedRequests>
    <add path="*">
        <traceAreas>
            <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
            <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
            <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket,RequestRouting" verbosity="Verbose" />
        </traceAreas>
        <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="500-999" />
    </add>
</traceFailedRequests>
```

- Since there are 100+ websites I have set `enabled="true"` in site defaults:

```xml
<siteDefaults>
    <traceFailedRequestsLogging enabled="true" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" maxLogFiles="50" />
```

- Finally I created a test page that throws error:

```
<%
Option Explicit
Response.Write a ' Variable is undefined: 'a'
%>
```

The error is logged in `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles` as expected but errors generated by the actual content pages are not. What is different about those pages is that they are called via Rewrite Module and the URL looks like https://example.com/about.html instead of https://example.com/about.asp

How to fix this?

Comment: My first guess is that changing the request to html is bypassing the pipeline configuration that has enabled FRT, but that's just a guess. never tried FRT for ASP Classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) there is a note that says:

> If the Failed Request Tracing was installed after URL rewrite module,
> the "Rewrite" area in Trace Providers may not be available. If you do
> not see "Rewrite" area listed there, go to Add/Remove programs and
> then run URL rewrite module installer in repair mode.

I reinstalled URL Rewrite module, then recreated the failed request tracing rule, making sure that "Rewrite" was present (and selected) in the "areas" section of "WWW Server" provider.

The failed requests were logged afterwards and contained information that was not present in the event viewer e.g. full URL of the faulting page and the stack trace